# Display error message while making Get api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am making a get api using node js and express js framework and this is the code which I am writing

controllers/biz_plans.js

```
const getbizPlans = (req, res, next) => {

    return db.coaching_classes.findAll({})
        .then(classes => {

            if (classes && classes.length > 0) {

                return res.status(200).send(classes)


            }

            else {

                console.log('not found');
                return res.status(404).send({


                    error_message: 'no classes available',

                });
            }


        })
        .catch(next);


};
```

and my routes.js is

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var db = require('../models');

var organizationsController = require('../controllers/bizPlans')

/* GET coaching_plans listing. */

router.get('/',organizationsController.getbizPlans);


module.exports = router;
```

If Data is there in the database this api is running but when data is not there in the database it should display the error message which I am trying to display but it is not displaying anything in the browser.
I am not able to understand what I am missing I have checked various links regarding this and everywhere same approach I found but it is not working for me .

Comment: Is the `console.log` printing the message?

Comment: No console.log is also not printing anything

Comment: Not able to understand why this is happening everything I am doing is correct then too getting error

Comment: @Vikas We need to see `db.coaching_classes.findAll` method too

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `catch` function to return the error?

```
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(404).send({
        error_message: 'no classes available'
    });
});
```

Comment: Nothing happened same issue is coming